# Self signed SAN certificate failed to be verifed

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, certificate

I followed this instruction to create a self-signed certificate
http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm. However, the certificate is always failed to be verified and my tls connection program can't setup connection using this certificate.

Any idea why and how to solve it?

The following is the commands to generate the certificate and result of verification.

```
$ openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -out public.csr -key private.key -config openssl.conf
$ openssl req -text -noout -in public.csr 
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in public.csr -signkey private.key -out public.crt -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.conf
$ openssl verify -CAfile public.crt public.crt 
public.crt: O = My Company, L = My Town, ST = State or Providence, C = US
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The following is the openssl.conf. The ip address is partially crossed out.

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file.
#

# Establish working directory.

dir                 = .

[ ca ]
default_ca              = CA_default

[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName         = match
organizationName            = match
organizationalUnitName          = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress                = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                = 1024          # Size of keys
default_keyfile             = key.pem       # name of generated     keys
default_md              = md5               # message digest    algorithm
string_mask             = nombstr       # permitted characters
distinguished_name          = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions              = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name             Prompt string
#-------------------------    ----------------------------------
0.organizationName          = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_max            = 40
localityName                = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName             = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min             = 2
countryName_max             = 2
commonName              = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max              = 64

# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name             Value
#------------------------     ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default      = My Company
localityName_default            = My Town
stateOrProvinceName_default     = State or Providence
countryName_default         = US

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints            = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier            = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier          = keyid:always,issuer:always

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints            = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier            = hash
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 1xx.1x.1xx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are generating is a self-signed root certificate. OpenSSL attempts to verify certificates by chaining certificates up to a trusted root that is present in its certificate store. Since yours is (obviously) not in that store it will always fail.

Here are three ways to get rid of the warnings:

**Disable certificate verification**

This is generally a bad idea because without certificate verification you have completely disabled the identity component of a TLS handshake. Use it only in development (and never let it leak to production!)

**Add your root certificate to the trust store**

This will work provided you're willing to install the certificate on every machine that needs to talk to this endpoint. (For OpenSSL this is a ca_bundle file that is located in a distribution specific location)

**Buy a cert from a CA**

The easiest, but also the one that costs $$$. If you do this then the site you're installing this certificate on will be trusted globally.